# Building my own brushless 3-phase motor driver to use with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, pcb, mosfet, brushless-dc-motor

For educational purposes I want to build from scratch a PCB that would allow me to control an hard disk motor I scavenged from the trash. To do so, I was thinking about using AO3400 and AO3401 (PNP and NPN) MOSFETS that come in the SOT23 package (they are rated for 4.9 Amps so I thought that should be enough). I designed a simple 2-sided PCB using Fritzing:

[image: PCB]

---

The idea would involve the upper part to go to the three wires of the motor, the 3 bottom-left side pins should be switched between logical 1 (5V) and logical 0 (GND) by an Arduino which I protect from draining too much current with the three 1kΩ 0805 resistors. Finally the bottom GND pin should connect both to the external batteries and the Arduino's GND and the VCC should get the 12V from the battery.

Since I am no expert (I barely know anything about electronics), I want to ask someone with more experience before I risk frying my Arduino: Would this work? If not, how should I change it?

EDIT: The three blue wires going from the resistors to the gates of the MOSFETs should be on the back side of the PCB.

Comment: Show a circuit.

Comment: If this is for educational purposes, at least use a proper schematic and PCB software. There are plenty of free alternatives out there.

Answer (score 3):

There is an effect you are probably unaware of, which is known as the "crowbar" effect.

MOSFETs do not switch from OFF to ON in one immediate change, and the do not switch from ON to OFF in a single immediate change.  There is a period where they are changing from ON to OFF or OFF to ON, during which they are conducting.

The gate terminal is basically a small capacaitor.  It takes time for it to charge fully, and it holds its charge briefly as it discharges.

During this time your Vcc and GND will effectively be short circuited - just like a crowbar dropped across a battery's terminals.

$$poof$$

To protect against this you need to engineer a "dead zone" between turning off one MOSFET and turning on the next.  This is commonly done using a MOSFET H-Bridge Driver chip (there are many), or by individually controlling the two MOSFETs in a channel.

Given that you are driving this from an Arduino, unless you are doing other things as well, you have plenty of IO pins.  By driving each individual MOSFET from an IO pin (resulting in 6 IO pins being used, not 3), you can be sure that you never turn on one MOSFET until a reasonable time after its partner MOSFET has been turned off.